# Querying for a set time?

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to query for a set time from a PHP script?

I want to write a PHP script that takes an id and then queries the MySQL database to see if there is a match. In the case where another user may have not yet uploaded their match, so I am aiming to query until I find a match or until 5 seconds have passed, which I will then return 0.

In pseudocode this is what I was thinking but it doesn't seem like a good method since I've read looping queries isn't good practice.

```
$id_in = 123;
time_c = time();
time_stop = time + 5; //seconds

while(time_c < time_stop){
     time_c = time()
     $result = mysql_query('SELECT * WHERE id=$id_in');
}
```

Comment: Do you want to delay the program execution for given number of seconds?

Comment: Can be with sleep?

     **sleep(5);
     echo "make something";**

Comment: I want to keep querying until I have found a match or until 5 seconds have passed. Wouldn't sleep make the program query once and then stop querying afterwards?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend continuously querying the mysql server as fast as it can for 5 seconds because it would overload the server. I would instead set some sort of threshold to query it every so many seconds with `sleep()` or microseconds with `usleep()`. This way instead of executing 1000 queries, you might execute 10. Also keep in mind that the script will appear to hang to the user during those 5 seconds, unless it's run behind the scenes somehow.

Comment: Are you using js/jquery in your project?

Comment: Planning on using a mobile app like android to execute the php script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your requirement is to poll some table until a row with a particular ID shows up.  You'll need a query like this to do that:

```
SELECT some-column, another column FROM some-table WHERE id=$id_in
```

(Pro tip: don't use `SELECT *` in software.)

It seems that you want to poll for five seconds and then give up. So let's work through this.

One choice is to simply `sleep(5)`, then poll the table using your query.  The advantage of this is that it's very simple.

Another choice is what you have. This will make your php program hammer away at the table as fast as it can, over and over, until the poll succeeds or until your five seconds run out.  The advantage of this approach is that your php program won't be asleep when the other program hits the table. In other words, it will pick up the change to the table with minimum latency.  This choice, however, has an enormous disadvantage.  By hammering away at the table as fast as you can, you'll tie up resources on the MySQL server. This is generally wasteful. It will prevent your application from scaling up efficiently (what if you have ten thousand users all doing this?) Specifically, it may slow down the other program trying to hit the table, so it can't get the update done in five seconds.

There's middle ground, however. Try doing a half-second wait

```
 usleep(500000);
```

right before each time you poll the table. That won't waste MySQL resources as badly. Even if your php program is asleep when the other program hits the table, it won't be asleep for long.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do simple polling and sleeping. I don't know your exact requirements, but in general your question asks for [`GET_LOCK()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock) or [PHP's Semaphore support](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sem.php).

Assuming your uploading process starts with

```
SELECT GET_LOCK("id-123", 0);
```

Your Query thread can then wait on that lock:

```
SELECT GET_LOCK("id-123", 5) as locked, entities.*
  FROM entities WHERE id = 123;
```

You might eventually find that a [`TRIGGER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/triggers.html) is the thing what you were looking for.